Conservation of energy and Coulomb's law
The Coulomb's law states:
$$F = k \frac{|q_1 q_2|}{r^2}$$
where $k$ depends to the medium between two charges. by replacing that medium with something that has a bigger value of k, the force between charges would increase, which means the charges would gain more kinetic energy after being released. How does it match conservation of energy law?

Firstly, you may need to distinguish velocity and kinetic energy from force and acceleration. Secondly, how would you like to replace the medium?

If you look at a table of actual values for materials, you will see a lack of "bigger value of k".

I'm not liking the absolute value on charges, since it means like and unlike charges repel.

The reason why a medium changes the effective value of $k$ is because the medium itself consist of charges. In more formal Maxwell equation formulations one actually distinguishes between the real electric and magnetic field, $\mathbf{E},\mathbf{B}$ and the fields modified by taking into account the polarization and magnetization of the medium, $\mathbf{D}, \mathbf{H}$. Thus, if we account for all the charges (the ones we consider in the Coulomb law and their interaction with the media), the energy conservation still holds.
See Maxwell equations: Macroscopic formulation

Consider a system of two point charges separated by a distance $r$.
In your equation $k=\dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{\rm r}\epsilon_0}$.
Increasing $k$ means that $\epsilon_{\rm r}$ must decrease, and this results in a larger electric potential energy of the system.
To effect the change of medium between the two charges positive external work has to be done on the system and this is where the increase in electric potential energy has come from.
This results in the force between the two charges increasing and hence if the separation of the charges is decreasing the amount of work done by the electric field is greater when $\epsilon_{\rm r}$ is smaller.

Consider a situation with the relative permittivity increasing.
Imagine the two charges in a vacuum, $\epsilon_{\rm r} = 1$.
Now place a small piece of dielectric material, $\epsilon_{\rm r} > 1$, near them.
The dielectric will have charges induced on it such that there is a net attractive force between the dielectric material and the two charges.
If the dielectric material is free to move it will move closer to the two charges, gaining kinetic energy as the system loses electric potential energy.

Your example:
The reason this matches with energy conservation (whether there are bigger $k$'s or not) is that changing the medium in between requires energy itself.
Consider the charges kept fixed at a certain distance but with a metal plate shielding off the electric field. In this setup the charges do not attract each other.
If we remove the metal plate the charges will feel attraction.  Therefore, the potential energy increases. But removing the plate requires external energy, since the plate is attracted by the two charges. Therefore, energy conservation is not violated.
More general question:
More general, this is the explanation why many of the perpetual motion machines do not work. I.e., changing some parameters (such as $k$) requires energy itself.
